# Render edges of VTK object possible?

Tags: xtk

Firstly, XTK is a very nice library!

Is it currently possible to render VTK object with surface + edges (in different color) with XTK? If this is not possible at the moment is it planned to be implemented in the future versions?

I tried to use X.object function .setType() but did not get it to work (not sure if it would help anyway, just experimenting).

Thanks, 
- Kimmo

Answer (score 0):

XTK can only parse one primitive of a .vtk file. This means, if multiple primitives like triangles and lines are defined there, only the last one gets configured in XTK. This will likely not change since the following is possible:

a) have 2 .vtk files where one includes the surface as f.e. triangles, and one the edges as lines. http://mindboggle.info does something similar.

b) we soon want to have wireframe mode support in XTK. then, you could load the same .vtk file two times, display one as a solid surface and one rendered as wireframe.

HTH!